# dynamically viewing and downloading pdf in django

Tags: django, pdf, dynamic, view, invoice

i want to view and download pdf of some invoices within a timepriod in my ecommerce web.there is no such data are stored in a table.i only want to disply invoices in pdf manner with in a time period.i gave my view function here.unfortunatly i couldnt display any data which i viewd dynamically.

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
template = get_template(template_src)
html  = template.render(context_dict)
result = BytesIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
return None



class ViewPDF(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    if request.method=="POST":
    date_from=request.POST.get("date_from")
    date_to=request.POST.get("date_to")
    select=request.POST.get("select")
    a=db_cart.objects.all().filter(updated_at__lte=date_to,updated_at__gte=date_from,stage=select,status=1)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('reportpdf.html',{'ob':a})
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')


class DownloadPDF(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pdf=render_to_pdf('reportpdf.html')
    response=HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    filename="report%s.pdf"%("12341231")
    content="attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
    response['Content-Disposition']=content
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing the context arguement to your `render_to_pdf` function. Also, as `render_to_pdf` is already returning a `HttpResponse`, try just returning `pdf` as follows:

```py
class ViewPDF(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}  # Add something to your context object here
        pdf = render_to_pdf('reportpdf.html', context)
        return pdf
```

Comment: the things is i want pdf view within a time period.that is i dont want to display any static content here.please check viewPDF again .i have currepted some code here

Comment: Sorry, Im not too sure what you are trying to say here. However, you are still not passing a context object to the `render_to_pdf` function with your `DownloadPDF` view. You are also still returning a `HttpResponse` within a `HttpResponse`, try changing that too.